# Json with arrays in c#

Tags: c#, json

I started to learn C# and some Json, I am trying to get this form of Json format:

[Desired Output :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uJNW.png)

I have tried this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myjason = new myJson
            {
                ContentDisposition = "",
                md5 = "da855ff838250f45d528a5a05692f14e",
                file_name = "MyFile.docx",
                features = new[] { "te" },
                te = new te { reports = new[] { "pdf", "xml" } },
               // images = new img { { a.id = "7e6fe36e-889e-4c25-8704-56378f0830df", a.revision = 1 }, { a.id = "e50e99f3-5963-4573-af9e-e3f4750b55e2", a.revision = 1 } }
            };



            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myjason, Formatting.Indented);
            Console.WriteLine(json);
        }
        public class myJson
        {
            public string ContentDisposition{ get; set; }
        public string md5 { get; set; }
            public string file_name { get; set; }
            public string[] features { get; set; }

            public te te { get; set; }
            public img images { get; set; }
        }

        public class a
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public int revision { get; set; }
        }

        public class te
        {
            public string[] reports { get; set; }
        }

        public class img
        {
            public a[] images { get; set; }

        }
```

And here is my current output:

[Current output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCiWs.png)

Please help, thanks a lot!

Comment: Please include code, not pictures of code, especially if you are requesting others to provide you with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content-Disposition and Content-Type are request headers so they don't need to be in your json body

Here I've also demostrated how you can set a custom json property name using JsonProperty attribute.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myjason = new myJsonClass
     {
    Request = new requestClass
    {
        md5 = "da855ff838250f45d528a5a05692f14e",
        file_name = "MyFile.docx",
        file_type = "docx",
        features = new[] { "te" },
        te = new te
        {
            reports = new[] { "pdf", "xml" },
            images = new a[] { new a { id = "7e6fe36e-889e-4c25-8704-56378f0830df", revision = 1 }, new a { id = "e50e99f3-5963-4573-af9e-e3f4750b55e2", revision = 1 } }
        },

    }
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myjason, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine(json);
        }

public class myJsonClass
{
    [JsonProperty("request")]
    public requestClass Request { get; set; }
}

public class requestClass
{
    public string md5 { get; set; }
    public string file_name { get; set; }
    public string file_type { get; set; }
    public string[] features { get; set; }

    public te te { get; set; }

}

public class a
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int revision { get; set; }
}

public class te
{
    public string[] reports { get; set; }
    public a[] images { get; set; }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "request": {
    "md5": "da855ff838250f45d528a5a05692f14e",
    "file_name": "MyFile.docx",
    "file_type": "docx",
    "features": [
      "te"
    ],
    "te": {
      "reports": [
        "pdf",
        "xml"
      ],
      "images": [
        {
          "id": "7e6fe36e-889e-4c25-8704-56378f0830df",
          "revision": 1
        },
        {
          "id": "e50e99f3-5963-4573-af9e-e3f4750b55e2",
          "revision": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are a bit confused about what's going on here. It looks like you're trying to POST some JSON to some endpoint.

`Content-Disposition` and `Content-Type` are HTTP headers. They are not JSON.

The JSON starts with the first `{` and this is the *body* of the POST. To create that body, you could use a C# object like:

```
public class MyJson {
 public class MyRequest request {get ;set;}
}

public class MyRequest {
 public string md5 {get;set;}
 public string file_name {get;set;}
 public string file_type {get;set;}
 public List<string> features {get;set;}
 public MyTe te {get;set;}
}

public class MyTe {
    public List<string> reports {get;set;}
    public List<MyImages> images {get;set;}
}

public class MyImages {
    public string id {get;set;}
    public int revision {get;set;}
}
```

And then use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` on a `MyJson` object. To set the HTTP headers depends on what you're trying to do and with which tools, and that probably belongs in a different question.

EDIT: I said "and so on" because it's really just a rote exercise, and there are [better tools to do this](http://json2csharp.com/) but I've updated.

Comment: Can you please add a *full*  code? what do you mean "and so on"? that's exactly where I got stuck

Comment: at least 15 rep are promised for full answer

Comment: thanks in advance for that big 15 rep, it will make a huge difference in my life